# Chain GUIs together in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a program in matlab that chains together several tested, functioning GUIs but I am having some trouble.

In one function I have:

```
global Status;
global value1;
Status = 'setup';


switch Status
    case 'setup'
        ADone = ASetup; %Calls setup function which should return a value when done
        if strcmp(ADone, 'yes')==1
            Status = 'Pos1';
        end
    case 'Pos1'
        value1 = OHMgui1;
        Status = 'Pos2';
    case 'Pos2'
       %Still work in progress 
end
```

And in my Asetup function I have:

```
function done = ASetup



AStatus = GUI1; 
BStatus = GUI2();
CStatus = GUI3();
DStatus = GUI4();

%Up until here everything goes as intended
Refstatus = RefGUI();




done = 'yes'; %Returns value when finished

disp (done) %Check statement, does not execute, error happens somewhere before here

end
```

GUIs 1-4 basically just display reference images with an OK button to close them, and I control them by using uiwait() and having them set a return value when the OK button is pushed (to make sure one doesn't trigger until the previous one is closed). This functions exactly as I would like.

However for RefGUI, I created it with a continue and a close button. I want the user to be able to click continue and have the program continue while RefGUI stays open. Ideally this would result in a call OHMGUI1, but it doesn't even seem to display the check statement.

I suspect the error is in RefGUI, which opens at the correct time, but I cannot get anything to happen after the continue or close buttons are pressed (with the exception of closing the GUI without the program continuing). Its code is:

```
function varargout = RefGUI(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @ClampRef_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @ClampRef_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end



function RefGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
matlabImage = imread('C:...reference.jpg');
image(matlabImage)
axis off
axis image
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
set(handles.pushbutton2,'enable','off') %Disable close button until continue is pressed



function varargout = RefGUI_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

uiwait();
global valueout;
varargout{1} = valueout;
%I have also tried disabling the above 3 lines with no difference.

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global valueout;
valueout = 'Finished';
set(handles.pushbutton2,'enable','on') %enable close button
set(handles.pushbutton1,'enable','off') %disable continue button
return



function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
closereq(); %close button closes GUI window
```

What can I do to make the program continue as intended?

Comment: I suspect you'll want a `uiresume` which clears the `uiwait` without actually closing the window

Comment: I tried adding uiresume to the continue button and now that makes the ui close, the test statement still is not executed

Comment: Actually I fixed another mistake and now this works!! Thanks!!!